# Databricks CLI Configuration Error "Please reconfigure with dbfs configure"

Tags: python, databricks, databricks-cli

I've installed and configured the Databricks CLI but get the error below when running

```
databricks workspace ls
```

**Error Returned:**

> Error: Your authentication information may be incorrect. Please reconfigure with dbfs configure

**Steps Used to Install CLI**

1) Installed using `pip install databricks-cli`
2) Configure with CLI `databricks configure --token`. My `~/.databrickscfg` file looks like:

```
[DEFAULT]
host = https://<account>.cloud.databricks.com
token = <password_generated_from_access_token
```

Has anyone come across this error and have a solution?

Comment: maybe you should ask databrick's authors. They shoud have forum for this. There is even link to support on main page.

Comment: My workaround was to use the Databricks API.

Comment: Have you tried to do `databricks workspace ls /Users/user_account` where "user_account" is actually your account?

Answer (score 9):

I was also getting the same error. What worked for me is something like this.

1. Generate a new PAT from databricks workspace user settings. Don't use the older one.
2. Use `databricks configure --token` command in your local system to be able to access the databricks-cli.
3. Make sure your token should be something like `dapi123....`

Answer (score 0):

Your access credentials are stored in the file `~/.databrickscfg` on Unix, Linux, or macOS or `%USERPROFILE%\.databrickscfg` on Windows. The file contains a default profile entry:

```
[DEFAULT]
host = <workspace-URL>
token = <Azure-AD-token>
```

Make sure the `.databrickscfg` file is updated.